# SSMS Stored Procedure - Update table

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, ssms

I'm running into some difficulty trying to take data in one table, aggregate it, and then paste it into another table. I'm not getting any errors, but when I click execute, nothing updates in the new table. I'm using a version of SSMS that was downloaded last year (version 14).

Table `OPEANSEAT_Hist` =

- table with OS_ID with multiple rows for [UPDATED_TIMESTAMP] that serves as versions (so one OS_ID could have 10 timestamps on a
  different row)
- Closed date is the initial [UPDATED_TIMESTAMP] the OS_ID was closed (there could be multiple [UPDATED_TIMESTAMP] after it was closed, I
  want the earliest one.

My new table: `OPENSEAT_CloseDates`

- OS_ID - numeric
- CLOSE_DATE - datetime

This table should only have 1 row per OS_ID with the CLOSE_DATE (or null if the OS_ID has not yet been closed)

This is what I have so far:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [PS_UPDATE_OPENSEAT_closedates]
AS
DELETE FROM [OPENSEAT_CloseDates]
UPDATE OPENSEAT_CloseDates

SET
    OPENSEAT_CloseDates.OS_ID = ( 
            SELECT t.OS_ID
            FROM [dbo].[OPENSEAT_Hist] t
            where t.OS_ID = OPENSEAT_Hist.OS_ID
            GROUP BY [OS_ID]),

    OPENSEAT_CloseDates.[CLOSE_DATE] = ( 
            SELECT MIN(CAST([UPDATED_TIMESTAMP] AS DATETIME))
            FROM [dbo].[OPENSEAT_Hist] s
            WHERE CLOSED_REASON IS NOT NULL AND s.OS_ID = OPENSEAT_Hist.[OS_ID]
            GROUP BY [OS_ID])

from OPENSEAT_Hist
```

Comment: why are you using delete statement and then update statement  on the same table ?

Comment: Its the simplest way to go about getting a static table for an analysis. I know there are better ways, I just want to keep it simple

Comment: FYI SSMS is only the client interface - it says nothing about the underlying version of the SQL Server database engine. And is not where the SP resides or runs.

Comment: Good information. What I'm looking for though is help with my stored proc. I'm still new at this. Any thoughts?

Comment: when you delete from a table with no where clause.. at the end of it.. the table is empty. So an update statement will do nothing as there are no records to update.. what you need is an insert from openseat_hist!

Comment: Thank you! Now that's an answer that is much more helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I realized I need to do INSERT instead of an update.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[PS_UPDATE_OPENSEAT_closedates]

AS
DELETE FROM [dbo].[OPENSEAT_CloseDates]
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO OPENSEAT_CloseDates
        SELECT 
            (SELECT MIN(CAST([UPDATED_TIMESTAMP] AS DATETIME))
            FROM [dbo].[OPENSEAT_Hist]
            WHERE OPENSEAT_Hist.OS_ID = t.[OS_ID]
            GROUP BY [OS_ID]) as CLOSE_DATE, 
            t.OS_ID

            FROM [dbo].[OPENSEAT_Hist] t
            where t.CLOSED_REASON is not null
            GROUP BY OS_ID

end
```